# key function for D3 join apparently has no effect

Tags: d3.js

I would like to use D3 for creating an HTML table from an array of objects such as this one:

```
const rows = [
  { name: "name1", // ...
  { name: "name2", // ...
  // ...
];
```

`rows` is continuously parsed from a JSON representation, so objects do change. I use the following join, including a key function:

```
const tr = tbody.selectAll('tr')
  .data(rows, function (row) { 
    return row.name; });
```

What I currently do observe and what surprises me is the following: During each iteration, the `enter` and `exit` selections in `tr` comprise nearly all the elements in `rows`. E.g. if the HTML table has 4 rows and the new array `rows` has only 3, then the two selections will comprise 3 and 4 elements respectively.

Why is this the case? Shouldn't the key function take care of this and ensure that in the cited example the `enter` selection is empty, and the `exit` collection contains the one element that gets deleted?

I've already checked in the inspector that each DOM `tr` element is indeed bound to a row such as `{ name: "name1", // ..` (i.e. its property `__data__` has this value), so what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE** Here is the code that builds the table and that accesses the `enter` and `exit` selections. The function is called whenever a new JSON representation has arrived (and was parsed into `rows`):

```
const cols = ['name', // ...

function process(rows) {
  const tr = tbody.selectAll('tr').data(rows, function (row) { return row.name; });
  const tr_enter = tr.enter()
    .append('tr')
      .attr('id', function(row) { return row.name; });
  const td = tr.selectAll('td').data(function (row) {
     return cols.map(function (col) { return row[col]; });
  });
  const td_enter = tr_enter.selectAll('td').data(row_to_array)
    .enter().append('td');
  td_enter.merge(td).text(function (value) { return value; });
  td.exit().remove();
  tr.exit().remove();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you actually build your table?

Comment: ...and where you're assessing the `enter` and `exit` selections, too?

Comment: Hm, I can spot no obvious mistake in the code you provided. The `name` values are unique across the entire dataset, right? At least they should be since you assign them to the `id` attribute. Can you put this in an executable demo?

Comment: @altocumulus Yes, names are unique. Putting this into an executable demo is not straightforward, because the serialization currently arrives over WebSockets. I'll see what I can do. I am using `d3.v5.js`, BTW.